# Gradle multi-project builds and IDEA, are modules not automated?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I was doing some experimenting with Gradle and created a multi-project build, with `multiproject_test` dependent on two projects `ChildA` and `ChildB`. I put this simple test project on GitHub.
https://github.com/thomasnield/gradle_multiproject_test

Everything seems to be working great on the command line and Eclipse. Everything was compiling and the dependencies were being recognized and used. But when I imported the project into IDEA it did not create the dependencies. It seems like I had to manually create the modules although it did import the source code from the child projects.

My question is do I have to specify these module declarations separately in the `build.gradle` script for IDEA? Why would it not even compile the dependencies?

***UPDATE***
Solution proposed below worked great. IDEA handled the `build.gradle`script much more gracefully than the `idea` plugin.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by _"when I imported the project into IDEA it did not create the dependencies"_?

Comment: Okay... before I opened up IDEA, I did a `clean`, `build`, and `idea` on the command line. Then I just opened up the project in IDEA expecting it to be configured and ready to go. but it was throwing compile errors because the dependencies were not recognized. I had to manually create modules for those child dependencies. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: From my experience the idea plugin does not work very well with IntelliJ. The right way to import a gradle project in IDEA is simply to import build.gradle and IDEA will take care of building an IDEA project from gradle code. Would this answers your need?

Comment: If what you say is true, then yes.

Comment: Give it a try and if it works I'll "formalize" it as an answer below

Comment: Worked beautifully, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading a Gradle project to build an IDEA project by using the `idea plugin` does not always work well. The recommended way to load a Gradle project in IDEA is to import the `build.gradle` file from the root project.

More detailed instructions can be found in IDEA documentation [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/importing-project-from-gradle-model.html).